# Do Not Cache And Preserve Form Scope

Tags: google-chrome, coldfusion, http-headers

Scenario - User posts a form from formSubmit.cfm to formAction.cfm which creates html data that should not be stored in the browser's cache.  It also has anchor tags to linkTarget.cfm.  If the user uses his browser to go back to formAction.cfm, he should be prompted by the browser to re-submit the form.

This can be accomplished by http-headers in general, which are made simpler with the `<cfheader>` tag.

The problem is that with Chrome, if I succeed in not caching the page, I lose the form scope.

Code Sample:

```
formSubmit.cfm
<form action="formAction.cfm" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submittedForm" value="submitMe" />
</form>


formAction.cfm (minus headers)
<cfif structKeyExists(form, 'submittedForm')>
<p>Form Scope exists</p>
<cfelse>
<p>Form Scope Does Not Exist</p>
</cfif>
<p><a href="linkTarget.cfm">Link to next page.</a></p>
```

The testing method was to clear the cache, and then look at it by browsing to chrome://cache/.  Once there, I would search for formAction.cfm.  Also, I would have to refresh the page each time I cleared the cache.

I tried various combinations of headers, but here are the most relevant.

```
<CFHEADER NAME="Cache-Control" VALUE="no-cache">
result - page was cached

<CFHEADER NAME="Cache-Control" VALUE="no-store">
result
page to confirm form resubmission
no form scope
```

Also, using Chrome's developer tools, the presence or absence of form data matched the result of the structKeyExists function.

How do I get Chrome to preserve form data without caching the page?

Comment: So you want the browser to cache the POST body of the request? There's no such a thing. Some browsers have their own ways to keep form data in case the users has to re-submit, but that has nothing to do with HTTP and there's no general way to control this. Wanting to cache a POST response seems wrong to begin with. How about POST-Redirect-GET (303 See Other)? If you need to store the POST request body regardless, you have to store/restore it on your own, e.g. using the session or the local storage (browser's web storage).

Answer (score 2):

Ran into some weird caching issues a while back.
have u tried giving a version-number with the page?

`<form action="formAction.cfm?V=#now()#" method="post">`

Comment: I'm looking for a more global solution.  Not mentioned in the question is that the cfheader tags are in a custom tag that is used in several Application.cfm (.cfc) files.